# Flask/Eve + WSGI and HTTP_X_HTTP_METHOD_OVERRIDE

Tags: python, flask, wsgi, eve

I am trying to understand how and when the WSGI environment HTTP Header(s) get renamed in an app's request object.

I am trying Eve and I am sending a POST or a PUT with X-HTTP-Method-Override.

The code, within Eve, is trying to access the request headers using the following code ([here](https://github.com/nicolaiarocci/eve/blob/2d76e7a2d3913695d46e129ef8ba55b2b6e8e07f/eve/utils.py#L341)):

```
return request.headers.get('X-HTTP-Method-Override', request.method)
```

In my WSGI Environment I have a HTTP_X_HTTP_METHOD_OVERRIDE with value PATCH.

When I try to do a request.headers dump, I get:

```
Request Header: ('X-Http-Method-Override', u'PATCH')
Request Header: ('Origin', u'http://localhost:9000')
Request Header: ('Content-Length', u'622')
Request Header: ('Host', u'localhost:24435')
Request Header: ('Accept', u'application/json;charset=UTF-8')
Request Header: ('Content-Type', u'application/json')
Request Header: ('Accept-Encoding', u'identity')
```

I checked online and other Python applications are trying to access this specific request header with the case:

**X-HTTP-Method-Override** and not **X-Http-Method-Override** (which I get in request)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flask takes care of extracting the headers from the WSGI environment variables for you, in the process removing the initial `HTTP_` prefix. The prefix is there in the WSGI environment to distinguish the headers from other WSGI information, but that prefix is entirely redundant once you extracted the headers into a dedicated structure.

The `request` object also provides you with a specialised dictionary where keys are matched *case insensitively*. It doesn't matter what case you use here, as long as the lowercased version matches the lowercased header key; `http`, `Http`, `HTTP` and `HtTp` all are valid case variations. That's because the HTTP standard explicitly states that case should be ignored when handling headers.

See the [`Headers` class reference](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.Headers) in the Werkzeug documentation, it is the bases for the `request.headers` object. It in turn is compatible with the [`wsgiref.headers.Headers` class](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/wsgiref.html#wsgiref.headers.Headers), including this:

> For each of these methods, the key is the header name (**treated case-insensitively**), and the value is the first value associated with that header name.

Emphasis mine.

Comment: In other words, it is a requirement of the WSGI specification that WSGI servers pass in headers in CGI style as 'HTTP_*'. Some frameworks will undo that so the original header names can be used.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton: exactly, and they do this because the WSGI environment contains more that headers, it is the `HTTP_` prefix that groups the information.